# Strange behavior from Core Data in iOS swift app

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift, core-data, xcode6

I am assigning non-nil values to entities, saving them, and then immediately retrieving them. But the values come back as nil. This is iOS 8.1 and Swift on Xcode (latest GA release) with identical behavior on both simulator and a device.

I have three entities: `Match`, `Score` and `Team`. Each `Match` has two teams, `team1` and `team2`. `Score` also has `team1` and `team2`. `Match` has a 1x1 relationship with `Score`, the fields being `bet` and `betFor` respectively. `Match` is identified by its field `matchNumber`.

So I have the following code:

```
    var match:CBMatch?
    var betCard:CBScore?
    for matchNum in 1...42 {
        match = CBMatch.lookup(self.managedObjectContext!, matchNumber: matchNum)

        betCard = CBScore.addForBet(self.managedObjectContext!, match: match!)

        betCard!.team1 = match!.team1
        betCard!.team2 = match!.team2

        match!.bet = betCard!

        println("For match \(matchNum), \(betCard!.team1.shortname) vs \(betCard!.team2.shortname)")
        // This is fine for all matchNum values
    }

    // Verify
    if true {
        var err:NSError? = nil
        self.managedObjectContext!.save(&err)
        if err != nil {
            abort() // Hasn't happened yet
        }
        match = CBMatch.lookup(self.managedObjectContext!, matchNumber: 1)
        betCard = match!.bet

        println("For match 1, \(betCard!.team1.shortname) vs \(betCard!.team2.shortname)")
     // Crashes with NPE
    // It complains that betCard!.team2 is nil but betCard!.team1 is fine
    }
```

Basically an attempt to retrieve the information I just set comes back as nil.

`CBMatch:lookup` and `CBScore:addForBet` are trivial:

```
class func lookup(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, matchNumber: Int) -> CBMatch? {
    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "CBMatch")
    var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "matchNumber == %d", matchNumber)
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    //        fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    // With or without didn't make a difference
    var err:NSError? = nil
    let matches = moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &err)!

    if matches.count == 1 && err == nil {
        let fetchedMatch = matches[0] as CBMatch
        return fetchedMatch
    }
    println("Could not find match \(matchNumber)")
    return nil
}


class func addForBet(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, match:CBMatch) -> CBScore {
    var entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("CBScore", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as CBScore

    entity.betFor = match
    return entity
}
```

I cannot simplify the data model by simply discarding bet.team1 etc, since there will be situations where bet.team1 and match.team1 will be different and I need to be able to compare them. For this (simplest) case they are identical, as this is the first time Score objects are being initialized.

I have tried several things, including returnsObjectsAsFault = false during the fetch etc. When I open the .sqlite file using sqlite3, I can see the entries being made. I tried using sql debug flag set to 3, but nothing jumped out. I am not saying that avenue is exhausted, but I definitely am.

Any thoughts on what could be going on here? I am stuck on this for quite some time and any thoughts would be appreciated.

The error is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, with the problem that `match.bet.team1` is nil . This is the same assignment I did barely a few lines above.

Comment: What is the error? Post the code that produces the error.

Comment: You still did not post the code that produces the error.

Comment: I updated the original post to reflect the code where the error occurs.

Comment: Maybe you have to use `match.bet.team1.description` for the string interpolation.

Comment: I think you should provide your real code, not pseudo-code (unless you think that the issue is with Core Data, which is not likely...)

Comment: updated question with the real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug in my code - the team1 and team2 relationships were 1:1, but in order for allowing multiple allocations they needed to be 1:N.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there is a flaw in your data model. You are referencing each team twice, which is really not necessary. The `Bet` entity does not need to know about the teams, as it has a to-one relationship with the `Match` entity. `Bet` could contain something along the lines of `firstValue` and `secondValue`.

While theoretically your setup should also work, you are introducing unnecessary complexity. You are not giving enough information to troubleshoot your error, but I think it is not necessary to even bother hunting down that bug.

Simply use `match.team1` instead of `match.bet.team1`.

BTW, the obvious thing to look out for is that either `match` is `nil`, `score` is `nil`, or `match.team1` is `nil` - in all cases `score.team1` is also `nil`.

Comment: It is quite possible that Match.team1 and Score.team1 would be different, and one or both could also be nil. Based on the state of the program the correct one would be used. In this particular (simplest) case they are the same as each other, but in other cases they will differ.

Comment: Again, I still think this is a design flaw. Think about how to eliminate this redundancy. See more obvious troubleshooting tips in my amended answer.

Comment: It is not a redundancy. I updated my text to reflect, hope that makes sense. But forget about the design for a minute, what could cause core data to not report an error during save, but not return the saved values in a fetch immediately after save? That's my main question.

Comment: See my amended answer. If the attribute is optional, it can be nil.

Comment: But that's the problem - I specifically set these attributes to a non-nil value, and when I read team back they came back as nil. Why would that happen? I changed my question to provide more information, please re-read the problem statement.